# Include apex variable in SOQL query

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, soql, apex

I have a visualForce page and an apex controller. I need to get a date value from my visualForce page into my Apex Controller (this is done already) and then pass this value into my SOQL query. My SOQL query runs fine when I put an actual date value in, but when I use the variable created before it says can't find variable named x.

I'm certain this is a general programming mistake, this is only my second week using code not clicks!

Let me know if you want to see the VF page too.

**Apex Controller***

```
global with sharing class GoogleChartsController2 {
    Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
    public Opportunity getProxyObject() {
        return o;
    }

    /**
      Loads all Opportunities and then filters 
    */
    @RemoteAction   
    global static Opportunity[] loadOpps() {
        return [select Id, Name, ExpectedRevenue, LeadSource, DaysToStartDate__c, Probability,   CloseDate, Amount from Opportunity WHERE CloseDate = :o.CloseDate ];
    }   
}
```

Section from VisualForce Page *****

```
<apex:page controller="GoogleChartsController2" sidebar="false"> 
<!-- Google API inclusion -->
<apex:includescript id="a" value="https://www.google.com/jsapi">

<apex:sectionheader title="Google Charts + Javascript Remoting" subtitle="Demoing - Opportunities  by Exepected Revenue">

<!-- Google Charts will be drawn in this DIV -->
<div id="chartBlock" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;">>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initCharts);

    function initCharts() {         
      // Following the usual Remoting syntax
      // [<namespace>.]<controller>.<method>([params...,] <callbackFunction>(result, event) {...}
      // controller : GoogleChartsController
      // method : loadOpps
      GoogleChartsController2.loadOpps( 
             function(result, event){

                 // load Column chart
                 var visualization = new    google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('chartBlock'));
                 // Prepare table model for chart with columns
                 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                 data.addColumn('string', 'Opportunity');             
                 data.addColumn('number', 'Days To Contract Start');
                 data.addColumn('number', 'Probability (%)');
                 data.addColumn('string', 'Lead Source');  
                 data.addColumn('number', 'Amount');  
                 // add rows from the remoting results
                 for(var i =0; i<result.length;i++){
                    var r = result[i];
                    data.addRow([r.Name, r.DaysToStartDate__c, r.Probability, r.LeadSource, r.Amount]); 
                  }
                // all done, lets draw the chart with some options to make it look nice.
                visualization.draw(data, {
                    legend : {position: 'right', textStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 10}},                         
                    width:window.innerWidth,
                    length:window.innerLength,
                    vAxis:{title: 'Probability', textStyle:{fontSize: 10}, minValue: 0, maxValue: 100},
                    hAxis:{title: 'Days Until Close' , textStyle:{fontSize: 10}, 
                    chartArea: {width: '50%', height: '75%'},  
                    sizeAxis: {minSize: 150, minValue: 150},
                    showTextEvery:1,slantedText:false}})
                  }, 
                  {escape:true});

      } 
</script>

</div></apex:sectionheader></apex:includescript>

 <apex:form >
      <apex:outputlabel value="Enter your name here"/>
      <apex:inputField value="{!proxyObject.closeDate}"/>
      <apex:actionsupport event="onclick" rerender="display" />   

      <apex:outputpanel id="display">
       <apex:outputtext value="The date entered is {!proxyObject.closeDate}"/>
      </apex:outputpanel>            
</apex:form>


</apex:page>
```

Comment: Are you populating `o.CloseDate` on the VF page somewhere? It doesn't look like you're querying/populating it anywhere in this code snippet, so your query is going to be looking for Opportunity records with a `CloseDate` of `null`.

Comment: Yes that's correct. Here's that line of the VF page: 

<apex:inputField value="{!proxyObject.closeDate}"/>

Comment: After some digging around I found out that I can't enter a bind variable into my SOQL query like that. It would need to be declared before as something like userDate so that it can be referenced inside the SOQL query. 

How and where do I do this? 

eg. -  Date userDate = o.CloseDate;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The need for remoting makes this a bit more interesting. Because remoting methods must be declared as static (as you've already done), you won't be able to reference any member variables that you're using in the controller. You can, however, pass along their value from the page in your remoting call.

First off, you'll want to modify your remoting method to accept a parameter from the Javascript that's calling it. Then you'll just parse that date string in your SOQL query. You can leave the `proxyObject` in the controller in order to leverage the out-of-the-box date picker that Salesforce provides, but you won't be referencing that variable directly in the `loadOpps` method.

```
global with sharing class GoogleChartsController2 {
    public Opportunity proxyObject {public get; public set;}

    public GoogleChartsController2() {
        proxyObject = new Opportunity();
        // just giving this a value for testing purposes
        proxyObject.CloseDate = System.today();
    }

    /** Loads all Opportunities and then filters */
    @RemoteAction   
    global static Opportunity[] loadOpps(String closedate) {
        return [select Id, Name, ExpectedRevenue, LeadSource, Probability, CloseDate, Amount from Opportunity WHERE CloseDate = :Date.parse(closedate)];
    }
}
```

Next, you're going to have to reference the field on your VF page when making the call to `loadOpps`. You can do this a couple of different ways, the easiest of which for these circumstances is probably to use the VF `$Component` merge field markup. This will require you to specify IDs for your nested VF tags:

```
<apex:form id="testForm" >
    <apex:inputField id="closedate" value="{!proxyObject.closeDate}"/>
```

And these can then be referenced like:

```
var dt = document.getElementById("{!$Component.testForm.closedate}").value;
```

So your final VF page becomes something like:

```
<apex:page controller="GoogleChartsController2" sidebar="false"> 
    <apex:sectionheader title="Google Charts + Javascript Remoting" subtitle="Demoing - Opportunities  by Expected Revenue" />

    <apex:form id="testForm" >
        <apex:outputlabel value="Enter a date here"/>
        <apex:inputField id="closedate" value="{!proxyObject.closeDate}" >
            <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" rerender="display" />
        </apex:inputField>
        <apex:outputpanel id="display">
            <apex:outputtext value="The date entered is {!proxyObject.closeDate}"/>
        </apex:outputpanel>            
    </apex:form>

    <!-- Google API inclusion -->
    <apex:includescript id="a" value="https://www.google.com/jsapi">

    <!-- Google Charts will be drawn in this DIV -->
    <div id="chartBlock" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;">>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
            google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
            google.setOnLoadCallback(initCharts);

            function initCharts() {         
              // Following the usual Remoting syntax
              // [<namespace>.]<controller>.<method>([params...,] <callbackFunction>(result, event) {...}
              // controller : GoogleChartsController
              // method : loadOpps
              var dt = document.getElementById("{!$Component.testForm.closedate}").value;
              GoogleChartsController2.loadOpps( dt, 
                     function(result, event){

                         // load Column chart
                         var visualization = new    google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('chartBlock'));
                         // Prepare table model for chart with columns
                         var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                         data.addColumn('string', 'Opportunity');
                         data.addColumn('number', 'Days To Contract Start');
                         data.addColumn('number', 'Probability (%)');
                         data.addColumn('string', 'Lead Source');  
                         data.addColumn('number', 'Amount');  
                         // add rows from the remoting results
                         for(var i =0; i<result.length;i++){
                            var r = result[i];
                            data.addRow([r.Name, r.DaysToStartDate__c, r.Probability, r.LeadSource, r.Amount]); 
                          }
                        // all done, lets draw the chart with some options to make it look nice.
                        visualization.draw(data, {
                            legend : {position: 'right', textStyle: {color: 'black', fontSize: 10}},                         
                            width:window.innerWidth,
                            length:window.innerLength,
                            vAxis:{title: 'Probability', textStyle:{fontSize: 10}, minValue: 0, maxValue: 100},
                            hAxis:{title: 'Days Until Close' , textStyle:{fontSize: 10}, 
                            chartArea: {width: '50%', height: '75%'},  
                            sizeAxis: {minSize: 150, minValue: 150},
                            showTextEvery:1,slantedText:false}})
                          }, 
                          {escape:true});

              } 
        </script>

    </div></apex:includescript>
</apex:page>
```

This seems to work for the most part for me, although the charting API is complaining about Column 2 being a string...but that's something you should be able to sort out by changing your columns around. Keep in mind that this currently won't re-render the chart whenever you change the date, but that shouldn't be difficult if you make a few changes to your `apex:actionSupport` tag.

Hope this gets you on the right track!

Comment: Thanks for this JCD, much appreciated. It's still saying variable does not exist on the SOQL query line when I try to save. How can I make that variable visible  (so to speak) from within the SOQL query?

Comment: Ah. This is almost certainly because of your `@RemoteAction` method being static, my mistake. Can you update your question to include the VF markup where you're calling this remote action from? And is there any reason you're using remoting instead of just calling a `PageReference` method to update the list of opportunities?

Comment: The @RemoteAction is so that I can populate a google bubble chart with Salesforce Opportunity data. This requires javascript remoting using the Google Visualization API & the analytics API.

Comment: Okay, but where are you actually calling the `loadOpps()` method? With remoting you should be able to pass in a date string parameter.

Comment: There you go, sorry my browser was stopping me from adding the code. Thanks

Comment: JCD, thanks so much for taking the time to help with this. I'm just running through the code now.